# iwlib.h Print BSSID of nearby Access Points

Tags: c, linux, wifi

So recently I've been looking into Beacon Frames and 802.11 packets in C and came across `iwlib.h` in Linux. I made a tiny snippet of code to show all nearby networks and their SSID. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iwlib.h>

int main() {
    wireless_scan_head head;
    wireless_scan *result;

    int sockfd = iw_sockets_open();
    iw_get_range_info(sockfd "wlan0", &range);
    result = head.result

    do {
        printf ("%s\n", result->b.essid);
        result = result->next;
    } while(result != NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Is there any way of extracting the BSSID/AP MAC address using this code in such a way I can print it like `FF:12:34:56:AB:CD` or `FF123456ABCD`? Any help will be much appreciated! Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the support to read the Mac Address is disabled in `iwlib`, there is an API `iw_get_mac_addr()` but it's disabled using `#if 0`

Refer:

- https://github.com/HewlettPackard/wireless-tools/blob/master/wireless_tools/iwlib.c#L2011.
- https://svn.dd-wrt.com/browser/src/router/wireless-tools/iwlib.c?rev=353&order=author#L1900

However the MAC address of a specific interface can be easily pulled using its socket descriptor.
The below C example code assumes the interface for WiFi has name "wlp3s0".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iwlib.h>

int main(void) {
  wireless_scan_head head;
  wireless_scan *result;
  iwrange range;
  int sock;
  struct ifreq s;

  sock = iw_sockets_open();

  if (iw_get_range_info(sock, "wlp3s0", &range) < 0) {
    printf("Error during iw_get_range_info.\n");
    exit(2);
  }

  if (iw_scan(sock, "wlp3s0", range.we_version_compiled, &head) < 0) {
    printf("Error during iw_scan.\n");
    exit(2);
  }
  
  strcpy(s.ifr_name, "wlp3s0");
  if (0 == ioctl(sock, SIOCGIFHWADDR, &s)) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
      printf("%02x", (unsigned char) s.ifr_addr.sa_data[i]);
      puts("\n");
  }

  result = head.result;
  while (NULL != result) {
    printf("%s\n", result->b.essid);
    result = result->next;
  }

  exit(0);
}
```